# Invalid parameter in select from database?

Tags: php, mysql

Its probley something small but i been looking at this for ages and still cant get it to work at all im getting two errors

Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in

Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number in

the code i have is this:

```
 public function getdata ($tran_id)
     {
        $sql = "SELECT tran_id, seller_user_name, user_name_buyer 
                FROM trade_transaction, feedback Where  feedback.feedback_username = trade.user_name_of_buyer 
              AND user_name_of_buyer = :user_name_buyer ";
         $sth = $this->db->prepare($sql);
         $sth->execute(array(':tran_id' => $tran_id, ':user_name_buyer ' => $_SESSION['user_name']));

         $user = $sth->fetch();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're binding a `:tran_id` parameter during your call to `execute`, but you're not using that parameter in your query.

Change your `execute` line to this

```
$sth->execute(array(':user_name_buyer ' => $_SESSION['user_name']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `:tran_id` from your parameter list or add a condition for that parameter. I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Your select statement does not have a where clause for tran_id, either remove the tran_id from your execute call

```
$sth->execute(array(':user_name_buyer ' => $_SESSION['user_name']));
```

or add a extra where clause to your sql statement

```
$sql = "SELECT tran_id, seller_user_name, user_name_buyer 
                FROM trade_transaction, feedback
          WHERE  feedback.feedback_username = trade.user_name_of_buyer
              AND tran_id = :tran_id 
              AND user_name_of_buyer = :user_name_buyer ";
```